# Sphero 2.0 Turning in place

Tags: sphero-api

I tried running mRobot.drive(0f, 90f); or RollCommand.SendCommand(mRobot, 90f, 0f); with my sphero 2.0 and it does not move really at all sounds like the motors are trying to twitch but don't.  Tried it with a sphero 1.0 and it works fine.  Same thing happens with SetHeadingCommand.sendCommand(mRobot, 90f); but no luck on the sphero 2.0.  Not sure if my sphero is bad but don't see why it runs on sphero 1 but not sphero 2 the same code.

Also when i open the Sphero app that you can download and initializes the ball it does not say there is any firmware updates.

Comment: Is the Sphero able to drive normally with the main Sphero app? If you have a bad motor, the ball will not be able to turn at all and it will make noises like it is trying.